# Como usar variable globales en python

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables

estoy intentando mantener el valor leido en un webhook en el siguiente webhook pero la variable que toma el valor no lo mantiene en el siguiente webhook.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request
import os
from threading import Thread

app = Flask(__name__)

xml = ""

def send_email(xml):
    print xml
    return None

@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST','GET'])
def webhook():
    xml = "hola"    
    t = Thread(target=send_email, args=(xml,))
    t.start()
    print "acabando"
    return '',200


@app.route('/response', methods=['POST','GET'])
def response():
    print xml #Comprobar como comparto la variable.
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 5000))
    app.run(debug=True, port=port, host='0.0.0.0', threaded=True)
```

El codigo recibe la primera llamada a /webhook, donde da a xml el valor "hola" y abre un hilo para ejecutar un codigo (imprimir el valor hola). Hasta ahi todo bien, pero ahora cuando hago la llamada a /response, me imprime un vacio, no imprime "hola" que es lo que necesito.

¿Alguna idea de como hacer que el valor que consigo en /webhook se quede para usar en /response?

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Quieres que la variable mantenga el valor entre peticiones http **distintas**? ¿Te sirve ponerla en la sesión (para no abusar de la magia de `werkzeug`)?

Comment: Exacto! El tema es que con la primera peticion HTTP voy a llenar esa variable con la info que me interesa. para la segunda peticion HTTP necesito esos datos. ¿Como lo hago para mantenerlos?

Comment: Antes de recomendarte algo más: ¿si vas a hacer esa variable *global* y *mutable* por qué no la declaras `global xml` y después la inicializas abajo? No obstante deberías pensar otro enfoque si tu app va a ejecutarse en producción.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay una diferencia importante entre acceder al nombre (lectura de la variable) y vincularlo dentro de un ámbito.

Tu asignas a la variable `xml` dentro del ambito local de `webhook` lo cual vincula ese nombre a este ámbito. Aunque existe también como variable global, lo oculta.

Si deseas poder asignar valores al nombre global, debes indicar explícitamente que se use la variable global y no cree una vinculación local. Esto se hace con la palabra reservada `global`.

Tu función debe quedar así:

```
def webhook():
    global xml
    xml = "hola"    
    t = Thread(target=send_email, args=(xml,))
    t.start()
    print "acabando"
    return '',200
```

Para leer la variable no es necesario pero si para asignarle valores.

Cuidado con lo que haces con la variable y donde y como la usas, más aún si metes asincronismo de por medio.

Comment: ¿Entonces la declaro global xml tanto dentro como fuera de /webhook? ¿o cuando la declaro fuera del webhook lo hago como xml =""?. Muchas gracias!

Comment: No, una variable declarada fuera de las funciones **ya es global**, solo debes usar `global` en aquellas funciones que modifiquen la variable (asigne valores). En este caso solo tienes que usar `global` en `webhook`, si las otras funciones solo leen la variable, pero no la modifican, no es necesario. Fuera de las funciones nunca se usa la palabra `global`, esta palabra no define la variable como global, solo le dice al intérprete que use una variable global dentro de una función. Saludos.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias por la ayuda!!!!!!