# ¿Por qué los cambios realizados en una función no se tienen en cuenta fuera de ella?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Quiero modificar una lista para agregar objetos dentro para hacerlos accesibles en la mano. Sin embargo, después de llamar a una función que crea estos objetos y los agrega a la lista, parece que no hay cambios.

```
# Restablecer los marineros y el barco.
sailors = []
resetSailors(sailors,mainBoard) # Hay un print(sailors) en la función.
print(sailors)
```

Sin embargo me devuelve :

```
[<__main__.Sailor instance at 0x000000000AA82288>, <__main__.Sailor instance at 0x000000000AA4C048>, <__main__.Sailor instance at 0x000000000AA4CE88>, <__main__.Sailor instance at 0x000000000AA58408>]
[]
```

Aqui esta el codigo de `resetSailors(sailors,board)`.

```
def resetSailors(sailors,board):
    # sets up sailors and boats.
    sailor_black_1 = Sailor('black',1,6,board)
    sailor_black_2 = Sailor('black',1,6,board)
    sailor_white_1 = Sailor('white',1,6,board)
    sailor_white_2 = Sailor('white',1,6,board)

    sailors = [sailor_black_1,sailor_black_2,sailor_white_1,sailor_white_2]

    boat_top_right = Boat(0,9)
    boat_top_left = Boat(0,2)
    boat_bottom_right = Boat(2,9)
    boat_bottom_left = Boat(2,2)
    print(sailors)
```

Comment: Mírate esta pregunta [Como usar variable globales en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/77913/15089) y ésta otra https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/176887/15089. En mi respuesta a ésta última, al final, se explica lo que te está pasando: estás reasignando un nuevo objeto `list` a tu variable dentro de la función (`sailors = [sailor_black_1, ..]`), lo que automáticamente crea una variable local a la función (con el mismo nombre que la global). No reasignes, solo modifica el objeto (`append`, `remove`, etc) o usa `global`.

Comment: @FJSevilla Estas de vuelta ! Espero que estés bien. Gracias por la información. Voy a ver

Comment: Si, estoy bien, ¡gracias! Mis ausencias solo se deben a una falta de tiempo grave para poder prestar la debida atención al sitio... XD. Volviendo a tu problema, está más o menos explicado en esas preguntas, la segunda de hecho es el problema inverso al que presentas (no quiere que la lista se modifique en la función). He decidido crear una respuesta, sobre todo para dar posibles soluciones a tu caso concreto. Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero es importante tener medianamente claros cuatro conceptos sobre Python:

- En Python el **paso de argumentos se hace mediante asignación**, es decir, la función recibe una referencia al objeto pasada por valor.
- Las **variables** no son más que **identificadores asociados a una referencia** a un objeto en memoria. Un mismo objeto puede tener por tanto multitud de variables asociadas a él.
- **Una variable definida en una función es por defecto siempre de ámbito local a la función**, es decir, nace y muere con ella y no puede ser accedida desde fuera de la misma. Esto incluye a los identificadores de los argumentos. Es siempre así a no ser que se indique lo contrario mediante `global`.
- **Hay objetos mutables** como `list`, `dict` o `set`, los cuales poseen métodos que permiten modificarlos una vez creados. **Otros objetos son inmutables** como `str`, `int`, `float` o `tuple`, en este caso, una vez creados no se pueden modificar, tenemos que crear un nuevo objeto siempre.

Resumiendo, cuando se llama a la función se crea un identificador `sailor` que pertenece a la función (**es independiente del identificador `sailor` global, aunque en este caso tengan el mismo nombre**). Este identificador `sailor` en tu función se asocia a una nueva referencia al objeto `list` que creaste globalmente. Esto permite acceder a dicho objeto desde la función sin problemas, ambos identificadores (el global y el local apuntan al mismo objeto en memoria).

El problema llega cuando **en tu función realizas una "re-asignación"** a la variable `sailor`:

```
 sailors = [sailor_black_1,sailor_black_2,sailor_white_1,sailor_white_2]
```

Ese `=` implica que se crea un nuevo objeto `list` y una referencia al mismo es asociada con `sailor`, desplazando la referencia anterior. La consecuencia es que la variable `sailor` de la función ahora apunta a un objeto distinto al que originalmente apuntaba (la que recibió como argumento). Cualquier cambio que hagas usando esa variable ya no es permeable al ámbito global, de hecho esa lista será destruida por el GC después de terminar la ejecución de la función.

Con esto más u menos claro, tienes varias opciones para solucionar tu problema concreto:

- Como llamas a la función desde el ámbito global, puedes seguir haciendo lo que haces pero usar el retorno de la función para reasignar en dicho ámbito la nueva lista. Sirve para objetos mutables e inmutables.

  ```
  sailors = ["Sailor1", "Sailor2"]
  print(sailors)

  def reset_sailors(sailors_list):
      sailors_list = ["Sailor3", "Sailor4"]
      return sailors_list

  sailors = reset_sailors(sailors)
  print(sailors)
  ```
- Lo anterior suele ser lo recomendable, pero siempre creamos un nuevo objeto, por eficiencia puede ser mejor modificar la lista (dado que es un objeto mutable) desde la misma función. En estos casos es recomendable siempre documentarlo bien, modificar variables globales, desde otro ámbito, puede ser confuso e incluso peligroso en algunos casos. Solo válido para objetos mutables, no para inmutables (si `sailors` fuera una tupla por ejemplo)

  ```
  sailors = ["Sailor1", "Sailor2"]
  print(sailors)

  def reset_sailors(sailors_list):
      sailors_list.clear()
      sailors_list += ["Sailor3", "Sailor4"] # similar a sailor_list.extend((...))

  reset_sailors(sailors)
  print(sailors)
  ```
- Se puede hacer lo mismo usando `global`, de esta forma la función no crea su propio identificador, sino que usa el global. No es que sea mucho de mi agrado, pero es otra opción. Válido para objetos mutables e inmutables.

  ```
  sailors = ["Sailor1", "Sailor2"]
  print(sailors)

  def reset_sailors():
      global sailors
      sailors = ["Sailor3", "Sailor4"]

  reset_sailors()
  print(sailors)
  ```
- Englobarlo todo en una clase si tu código conceptualmente coincide con el paradigma de la POO, haciendo que la función sea un método de instancia y `sailor` un atributo de instancia. Válido para objetos mutables e inmutables.

  ```
  class Game:
      def __init__(self):
          self.sailors = ["Sailor1", "Sailor2"]

      def reset_sailors(self):
          self.sailors = ["Sailor3", "Sailor4"]

  game = Game()
  print(game.sailors)
  game.reset_sailors()
  print(game.sailors)
  ```

> Por si alguien se lo pregunta, el operador `+=` (o `-=`, `*=`, `//=`, `/=`, etc) puede inducir a pensar que lleva a cabo una resignación igual que `=`, pero esto no es así cuando el objeto es mutable. Generalmente intentarán llevar a cabo la operación in-place, de no ser posible (objeto inmutable) crean un nuevo objeto resultado de la operación y si que reasigna.